# "available (availability)" vs. "valid (validity)" for "having sufficient power or efficacy" in AmEng vernacular

Tags: american-english, word-usage, ambiguity, dialects

Per Random House Webster's College Dictionary, Ed. 1991,

***available***

> 1. suitable or ready for use; of use or service; at hand:
>      *I used whatever tools were available*.
> 2. readily obtainable; accessible:
>      *available resources*.
> 3. [**Having sufficient power or efficacy; valid**](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22california+surplus+mart%22&biw=391&bih=257&prmd=mnsiv&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIn93qu-XKAhXMXhoKHZ35Bx0Q_AUIBCgA#q=%22having+sufficient+power+or+efficacy%3B+valid%22).

***valid***

> 1. sound; just; well-founded: *a valid reason*.
> 2. producing the desired result; effective:
>      *a valid antidote for gloom*.
> 3. **having force, weight, or cogency; authoritative**.
> 4. **legally sound, effective, or binding; having legal force**:
>      *a valid contract*.

Per Collins-Robert English-French Ditionary, Ed. 1985,

***availability***

> *n*
>
> (a) [*material, people*] disponibilité *f*
>
> (b) (*US: validity*) validité *f*

***available***

> *adj*
>
> (a) *personnel* disponible; *thing* disponible, utilisable
>
> (b) (*US: valid*) valable, valide (*for* pour)

My question is, what's the difference between "available" and "valid" in the sense "having sufficient power or efficacy"?

In addition, absent clear context, "can't the word "available" sound sort of ambiguous as to whether it's "obtainable/accessible" or "having sufficient power or efficacy" that actually is meant?

Please, consider the following example:

> *The period for which these tickets are **available** is 3 months*
>
> *The period of **availability** for these tickets is 3 months*

could be understood as meaning,

> *The period for which these tickets are **obtainable/accessible** is 3 months*

But also,

> *The period for which these tickets are **valid (=effective)** is 3 months*

Comment: I don't think *available* can be used in the sense of *effective* for your tickets example. You'll need to use *valid* there. You could say that you might *make* some service *available* for 3 months (similar to *valid* for 3 months) - e.g. *If you purchase this ticket, the theatre will be made available to you for 3 months.* What example does your dictionary give for the third sense of *available*?

Comment: @Lawrence None. However, Harrap's English-French Dictionary states for "available:" (Chiefly AmEng) (of train ticket, etc.) valable, bon, valide (pour deux mois, etc.); utilisable; period for  which a ticket is available, durée de validité d'un billet.

Comment: @PeterShor Or Harrap's is giving a BrEng usage, erroneously marking it as AmEng. This sometimes happens with bilingual dictionaries. Collins-Robert's definition is more ambiguous, though, as to what actually is meant by "available (US: valid)." My guess is that it's the political sense of "available" that is supported here. E.g. C'est un candidat valable (Fr.); He's a valid candidate (BrEng/AmEng); He's an available candidate (Chiefly AmEng). http://www.wordreference.com/fren/valable

Comment: @PeterShor https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=list+of+available+candidates&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=6&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clist%20of%20available%20candidates%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/available), definition 2.

> Available: **valid**—used of a legal plea or charge.

Similarly, the OED says:

> 1b: in *Law*. Valid.

It's a specialized usage, and cannot be used for concert or train tickets. The OED also gives a (probably obsolete) U.S. political sense of *available*; it seems that a candidate was *available* if he had a good chance of winning. However, this really isn't a synonym of *valid*.

ADDED:

The word *available* can mean *valid* for train tickets in the U.K. and other countries, but I have never seen this usage in the U.S. See the comments.

Comment: UK train tickets **do** use "available" to mean "valid" in the sense that you can avail yourself of them on certain routes. They are able to be availed of. http://i.stack.imgur.com/N3BJA.jpg

Comment: @Andrew: If you google, you can find this usage in the form of phrases like *"return ticket available for six months"*. This appears to be mainly an outdated British usage, which is still extant in foreign countries and the Caribbean.

Comment: It's not outdated at all; it's still alive and well. I attached an image of a current ticket.

Comment: @Andrew: which uses both *valid* and *available*. Nice.

Comment: On the legal usage - perhaps it's related to *available defences* - if a defence is *available*, it is a *valid* defence. E.g. (Canadian - close enough to AmE?): ["Where a person intends, or actually causes, significant harm or death, consent is not an available defence as per the case law and the Criminal Code of Canada."](http://defence-law.com/assault/).